# SendMessage to .NET console application

Tags: c#, .net, ipc, sendmessage

I have been experimenting with sending messages from two .NET Windows Forms applications using `WM_COPYDATA`, and it works great.

I would like to know if that can be accomplished with console applications.

After all the `SendMessage` function takes in a window handle, how can I get the window handle of a console application?

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lParam);
```

Also do I need to set up some kind of message loop in the console application to be able to receive messages?

Comment: @GX: in the first link in my answer, there is an updated version of the code that caters for windows services and consoles...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) methods (aside from `WM_COPYDATA`) are memory-mapped files and named pipes. I suggest you check out the latter.

MSDN has an [example of named-pipe communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx). Specifically the classes you need to use are `NamedPipeServerStream` and `NamedPipeClientStream`, which behave largely like ordinary network streams once they're created.

The nice thing is that it also works over a network, although you can obviously use it on a single machine as well.

Setting up an actual Windows message loop in a console application is complicated, to say the least. If you really need to do it, here's a rather long-winded [article on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163417.aspx). I'd strongly recommend using named pipes instead if all you want to do is transfer data; if you don't actually need to handle standard Windows messages then this isn't going to be worth the effort.

Comment: Yes I have hear about Named Pipes, never actually tried to implement them.

Thank you for the nice resource links

Answer (score 2):

@tommieb75: XDMessaging is actually my library :) WM_COPYDATA doesn't work for console applications as they don't have a message pump. The library does however include a IOStream based IPC implementation that works for console apps and services. http://thecodeking.github.com/XDMessaging.Net/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I didn't have enough rep at the time of posting to add a comment.