# Send message or command from Winform Application to Console(cmd.exe)

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SendMessage to .NET Console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376237/sendmessage-to-net-console-application)

I would like to ask about how can I send the message or command to console from Winform application. About my code that is console application(cmd.exe) in winform. I can put in cmd.exe in winform bout i could not send message or command to console (cmd.exe).

Please see my code and help me

```
void PictureBox1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo start = new  
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    System.Diagnostics.Process bob = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    bob.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    bob.StartInfo.Arguments += " /K TITLE CMD";
    bob.StartInfo.FileName =  "cmd";
    bob.Start();
    this.timer1.Enabled = true;
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process bob = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    bob.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    bob.StartInfo.Arguments += " /K TITLE Command Prompt";
    bob.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD";
    bob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    bob.Start();
    this.timer1.Enabled = true;
}


private void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IntPtr hwnd ;
    hwnd = Usr32.FindWin("ConsoleWindowClass", "cmd");
    if (hwnd != System.IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        IntPtr hwndChild = IntPtr.Zero;
        hwndChild = Usr32.FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd, new IntPtr(0), null, null);
        if (hwndChild != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Usr32.SendMessage(hwndChild, 0x000C, 0, "Hello Everyone");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Get the Child Handle :( !");
        }
     }
     else

        MessageBox.Show("Application is not running");
}
```

Comment: A "workaround" that might work for you (depending on the console application in question), might be to interact with it using its regular standard input stream. See [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11767654/21567) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Console applications typically do not have a message pump and therefore cannot receive Windows messages unless it actively cooperates by creating one or pumping messages manually. This is not an option unless you own the source, which in this case you do not.