# C# equivalent of posttrheadmessage to another process

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke, ipc

I have codes written in native C++ that controls other processes ("client processes") created by CreatePrcess() and other Windows APIs
Then client processes (console, single-thread) wait for the message MSG_OK from the "server" process and resume running when the message is received.
I used PostThreadMessage() and it worked fine.

```
int MSG_OK = RegisterWindowMessage("MSG_OK");
void run(TCHAR* path) {
    STARTUPINFO si={0,}; si.cb=sizeof(STARTUPINFO); si.dwFlags=0;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    CreateProcess(NULL, path, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    Sleep(1000); // Just for simplicity. Actual code is message-based
    PostThreadMessage(pi.dwThreadId, MSG_OK, 0, 0);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);   // closing process handle makes usage count 1
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);    
}
```

Now I'd like to rewrite the code in C#, using p/invoke's as little as possible.
The following is the code I'm working on:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool PostThreadMessage(uint threadId, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

public void run(string path) {
    Process proc = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();
    si.FileName = path;
    proc.StartInfo = si;
    proc.Start();
    uint threadId; // <----?
    PostThreadMessage(threadId, MSG_OK, 0, 0);
    proc.Dispose();
}
```

I found C# classes such as Process and ProcessStartinfo but couldn't find any member similar to dwThreadId. Is there any?

EDIT: Since the client process is a single thread app,

```
 proc.Threads[0].id
```

seems to be the threadId I'm looking for. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: maybe will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376237/sendmessage-to-net-console-application

Comment: PostThreadMessage() is very troublesome.  Use a pipe instead, also well supported in C# without having to use pinvoke.

Comment: By using PostThreadMessage() I could avoid multithreading and other issues of synchronization. In my opinion as far as the client process is single-threaded and doesn't have UI that handles user input, it is easier to implement the server using PostThreadMessage than using pipes. Is there any other disadvantage of using PostThreadMessage given those restrictions on client processes?

Comment: @HansPassant pipes are the worst alternative to PostThreadMessage one could offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679243/getting-the-thread-id-from-a-thread).

I would consider using some other approaches like [mutexes, events or semaphores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).